# COUNT and SUM are multiplying when using multiple LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, sum

It's been a while since I've done any MySQL, so I'm probably just forgetting something basic here - but here's my situation:

(Simplified version of my tables)

**Table A** (2 rows)

d_id

d_nm

d_active

**Table B** (10 rows which match d_id #1, 0 rows which match d_id #2)

t_id

t_nm

d_id

t_active

**Table C** (11 rows which match d_nm #1 (total 496), 0 rows which match d_nm #2)

c_id

c_nm

d_nm

size1

size2

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    a.d_id,
    a.d_nm,
    COUNT(b.t_id) AS tcount,
    SUM(c.size1+c.size2) AS size 
FROM TableA a 
LEFT JOIN TableB b 
ON (b.d_id=a.d_id AND b.t_active=1)
LEFT JOIN TableC c 
ON (c.d_nm=a.d_nm)
WHERE a.d_active=1 
GROUP BY a.d_id,a.d_nm 
ORDER BY a.d_nm
```

**Expectation:**

d_id --- d_nm --- tcount --- size

1 ------- d1 ------- 10 -------- 496

2 ------- d2 ------- 0 ---------- 0

**Actual Result:**

d_id --- d_nm --- tcount --- size

1 ------- d1 ------- 110 ------- 5,456

2 ------- d2 ------- 0 ---------- 0

For some reason, it's multiplying the result of `tcount` by the number of records in `size` - and vice versa.  I'm assuming it's an issue with either my Join, or my Group By...but can't seem to get it to come out right!

Answer (score 1):

Came up with this, which works. Instead of doing regular Left Joins to the full table, I only Left Joined to the query results from the table. Since my data size is quite small at the moment, the time to run both queries is comparable. Not sure if there would be any performance hits as the size of the tables grows? If anyone knows of a better way please let me know!

```
SELECT a.d_id,a.d_nm,b.tcount,c.size FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN(SELECT d_id,COUNT(t_id)AS tcount FROM TableB WHERE t_active=1 GROUP BY d_id)b ON(b.d_id=a.d_id)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT d_nm,SUM(size1+size2)AS size FROM TableC GROUP BY d_nm)c ON(c.d_nm=a.d_nm)
WHERE a.d_active=1 ORDER BY a.d_nm
```